How to measure API time consumption step wise?
i have an API written in Spring boot , which just act as a proxy between two api's , it took request from one api and forward the request to other api , for 50% of request it is working fine but for some requests  it is taking too much time like 147ms , it should do it's work in around 20-40 ms , in the code i see nothing too complex , so i want to measure the time taken from checkpoints to checkpoints , like i want to know which step is time consuming
How can i do that ?
Some of my assumptions are if payload is coming too large, it might take some time but that's just a wild guess , idk what's the reason.

The answer you want is probably to measure things manually step by step via a Stopwatch class (Guava or Apache Commons Lang). The answer you need is tracing and, more importantly, profiling. A little more involved, but pays off immensely and shows you where exactly your application is spending time.

@PetrJaneček Your Comment would make a good Answer.

I thought it was sub-par, but indeed there's likely nothing to really be added without more context in the question. I added the answer, thank you.

The answer you want is probably to measure things manually step by step via a Stopwatch class (Guava or Apache Commons Lang).
The answer you need is tracing (integrated with Spring Boot, or e.g. via Glowroot) and, more importantly, profiling (IntelliJ profiling uses the great async-profiler under the hood, so just use that or async-profiler directly with a flamegraph output).
A little more involved, but pays off immensely and shows you where exactly your application is spending time while processing those requests.
